# Ionic native transitions not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, transition

The transitions are not working.

I am using https://github.com/shprink/ionic-native-transitions.

I added the files, I added 'ionic-native-transitions' in my app.js

What I am trying to do is to change the transition when navigating between two pages.

In page 1: I have a list

```
<div class="item item-text-wrap" ng-click="post($event,res)"  ng-repeat="res in result " >....
```

and when an item is clicked,

```
 $scope.post =  function($event, res){
    console.log(angular.element($event.target).parent());
    dataShare.sendData(res)

    $state.go('Details')

     window.plugins.nativepagetransitions.slide(
    {"direction":"up"},
    function (msg) {console.log("success: " + msg)}, 
    function (msg) {alert("error: " + msg)}
  );

  }
```

What happens is that it goes to page 2. But there is no error and in the console I get this error

> Cannot read property 'nativepagetransitions' of undefined

Comment: check if the plugin is installed for the platform that you are running. It might be installed for another platform and not the one you are checking.

Comment: it is installed I checked

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this cordova plugin cordova plugin add com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions
see this documentation https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/NativePageTransitions